# How long is Warzone mode?

Tags: worms-reloaded

I reached level 10 of Warzone single player mode on Worms:Reloaded. But how long does it last? Will I get something special if I finish it? Just asking because is a little boring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 31 Warzone levels. They don't offer any reward. ([wiki article](http://worms.wikia.com/wiki/Worms:_Reloaded#Warzone))